# PQescapeLiteral not defined?

Tags: postgresql, libpq, libpqxx

This is about the most basic libpq example I could think of to illustrate my problem.  The goal here is just to print out the escaped string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <libpq-fe.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    PGconn *db;
    char connstring[] = "dbname=TheInternet";
    db = PQconnectdb(connstring);
    char url[] = "http://www.goo'gle.com/";
    cout<<PQescapeLiteral(db, (const char *)url, (size_t) strlen(url))<<"\n";
}
```

When I compile with:

```
g++ PQescapeLiteral_test.cpp -lpq
```

or even with:

```
g++ PQescapeLiteral.cpp -I/usr/include/pgsql:/usr/include/pgsql/server:/usr/include/pgsql/server/libpq -lpq
```

I get the error:

```
PQescapeLiteral.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
PQescapeLiteral.cpp:12: error: ‘PQescapeLiteral’ was not declared in this scope
```

I found PQescapeLiteral in the manual for pgsql 9.0 in section 31.3.4.: Escaping Strings for Inclusion in SQL Commands.  I have the most recent version of libpq and libpq-devel from yum so I'm pretty sure it's supposed to be defined.

If someone can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine for me, with PostgreSQL 9.0.1 headers. Which version of the postgresql headers and library are you using? PQescapeLiteral was apparently added in 9.0: http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/release-9-0.html#AEN104548

Where are you expecting libpq.so to be? You show a compiler command with -I switches to locate the headers files in a non-standard location, but no corresponding -L switch to locate the libary.

Comment: libpqxx i686 1:3.0.2-4.fc13 fedora
 libpqxx-devel                            i686                            1:3.0.2-4.fc13                             fedora...postgres 8.4.5...this might be it!  I'll try installing the latest :)